# Can see the network share directly, but not from JAVA >> jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found

Tags: java, networking, web-applications, smb

I can expand the code if needed, but generally this is what is happening

(from Windows machine)

```
explorer \\hostname\folder1\folder2
```

=> works, I can see the contents

from Java

```
import jcifs.smb.*;

<..snip..>

String dest = "smb://hostname//folder1//folder2//file1.txt";

NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain,username,password);
SmbFile file = new SmbFile(dest, authentication);
```

**jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found**

Does this mean something is not supported? Tried single and double slashes.

Comment: Have you tried the same UNC path that you do with your Explorer command?

Answer (score 0):

The double slashes are required only after the protocol. Look at the difference here:

```
smb://hostname//folder1//folder2//file1.txt
smb://hostname/folder1/folder2/file1.txt
```

Also be aware that jcifs is a SMB implementation purely in Java. While the [original jcifs library](https://www.jcifs.org/) is no longer maintained (and since  Windows 10 connections based on that old protocol are no longer accepted) be sure to use a more up to date version of the library, such as [jcifs-ng](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng).

Comment: That's true of course since it's a URL. Will the UNC path work too